# Simplest way to check if multiple items are (or are not) in a list?

Tags: python

I want to use syntax similar to this:

```
if a in b
```

but I want to check for more than one item, so I need somthing like this:

```
if ('d' or 'g' or 'u') in a
```

but I know it doesn't work.

so I did it this way:

```
for i in a:
    for j in ['d','g','u']:
        if i==j
```

and it worked,
but I wonder if there's a simpler way.

Comment: It should return true if __all__ elements are in the list or just a subset of them?

Comment: or perhaps if **any** of the elements are in the list?

Comment: Check: [**any**](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any) and [**all**](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#all) in the documentation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`any`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any) and [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#all) can be used to check multiple boolean expressions.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 2, 4]

print(all(i in a for i in b)) # Checks if all items are in the list
print(any(i in a for i in b)) # Checks if any item is in the list
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `any` plus a generator:

```
if any(x in d for x in [a, b, c]):
```

Or check for set intersection:

```
if {a, b, c} & set(d):
```

Comment: so this expression (x in d for x in [a, b, c]) is a generator that compares an x in d with an x in [a,b,c] and vice versa?