# Check if any two items are present within another list

Tags: python, list

How to check if any two items of a list are within another list?

I am trying work out how to test if certain combinations of words appear within a list. For example:

```
l1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']

if all(['A', 'C', 'D']) or all(['A', 'D']) or all(['C', 'D'])in l1:
    print('Violation')
```

The idea is to determine if either (or both) `A` and `C`exist together with `D`.

I have tried the code above, but I am always getting a violation as I assume it is only testing if a single item for any of the check lists are within `L1`?

Comment: What do you think `all(['A', 'C', 'D'])` is?

Comment: I suspect this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22673813/7644596) is where you got your idea from.  If you didn't, it is a good example anyway, and easy to find in stackoverflow.  Just make sure you implement it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say, if all(['A', 'C', 'D']), each of the letters is converted to a True boolean, thus making the all() statement true, and "Violation" will always be printed. Here's a way to fix that:

```
l1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
pattern1 = ['A', 'C', 'D']
pattern2 = ['A', 'D']
pattern3 = ['C', 'D']

for pat in [pattern1, pattern2, pattern3]:
    if all(letter in l1 for letter in pat):
        print("Violation")
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for these subsets, you will have to check each one separately. Your use of `all` is also improper. `all` checks whether all elements of the sequence passed to it are ["Truthy"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/4909087).

```
all(['A', 'B', 'C'])
# True
```

So your `if` actually reduces to:

```
if True or True or True in l1:
```

The expression short circuits to `if True`, so this is *always* executed.

---

I would to this by performing a `set.issuperset()` check for every subset on `df`'s columns.

```
subsets = [{'A', 'C', 'D'}, {'A', 'D'}, {'C', 'D'}]
columns = set(df)
if any(columns.issuperset(s) for s in subsets):
    print('Violation')
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I understand your question exactly...

This code checks if ['A', 'D'] `and` ['C', 'D'] exist in l1.

```
if all(i in l1 for i in ['A', 'D']) and all(i in l1 for i in ['C', 'D']):
    print('Violation')
```

If you want `or` condition,

```
if all(i in l1 for i in ['A', 'D']) or all(i in l1 for i in ['C', 'D']):
    print('Violation')
```